# Can't push to beanstalk

Tags: ruby, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to use [php git deploy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.sdlc.html) for AWS Beanstalk

I got python, ruby etc installed. I setup the repository, did a `git aws.config` which went well. Then whenever I try to run `git aws.push` I get this error.

```
./.git/AWSDevTools/aws/dev_tools.rb:53:in `host': private method `split' called for    nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from ./.git/AWSDevTools/aws/dev_tools.rb:112:in `signed_uri'
        from .git/AWSDevTools/aws.elasticbeanstalk.push:86
```

Don't know much about ruby, but from what I gather it looks like it's missing a dependency maybe? I guess I'm not sure what's wrong, any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same problem, and I tracked it to a missing appRoot/.elasticbeanstalk/config file.

I added the file with the following content. Note: substitute your actual app/environment where appropriate.

**.elasticbeanstalk/config >>**

```
[global]
ApplicationName=your-application-name-east
DevToolsEndpoint=git.elasticbeanstalk.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
EnvironmentName=your-environment-name
Region=us-east-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I did some digging through the source files. Turns out there was a permissions issue in a config file so it was creating a null class, and thus you can't string split a null.